# Prevent Master Page reload in asp.net after Angular JS function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, angularjs

I have a page named StockGraph.aspx which has the HTML

```
<div ng-controller="StockGraphController">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 sub-head">
                    <h2 data-wow-delay="0.3s" class="wow rollIn animated"><strong>STOCK QUOTE </strong></h2>
                    <p data-wow-delay="0.3s" class="sub-head">Type In any Company name in the below Text Box to obtain the current stock value of the corresponding Company </p>
                    <label data-wow-delay="1.3s" class="wow rollIn animated">Try typing "Apple" </label>
                    <input type="text" id="symbolsearch" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter company name or symbol" ng-model="equitystock.symbol">
                    <button ng-click="showquote(equitystock)" class="btn btn-success">Show Quote</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12  sub-head">
                    <div id="chartDemoContainer" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px; margin-bottom: 30px;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My angular Controller is defined like this,

```
    function StockGraphController($scope) {

            $scope.showquote = function () {
                var dur = 365;
                var stockSymbol = $scope.equitystock.symbol;
                new Markit.InteractiveChartApi(stockSymbol, dur)
            }
 }
```

I have placed the angular function in the Master file. the above angular function calls the Stock api and displays the chart in the div id="chartDemoContainer". This function works fine in a simple standalone aspx file. But when i design the same scenario using the Master ->Child aspx page design, the angular function after retrieving the data, refreshes the page which inturn refresh the Master Page also, hence my graph to be loaded gets lost!!!! because of the master page refresh. Is there a way to stop the master page from being refreshed or any way in the angular directive ??

Please help on the issue??

Comment: where is your `ng-controller`?

Comment: i have placed the ng-controller in the above divs  <div ng-controller="StockGraphController">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row text-center">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 sub-head">
                        <h2 data-wow-delay="0.3s" class="wow rollIn animated"><strong>STOCK QUOTE </strong></h2>